# Gradle distribution plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

I have to create zip, tar.gz and tar.bz2 and include src, build.gradle and exclude .* files..

```
    <format>zip</format>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
    <format>tar.bz2</format>
```

so I have created below distribution in build.gradle but this will create sample.zip and sample.tar.
**how to create tar.gz and tar.bz2 using distribution plugin **

```
distributions {
main {
baseName = 'Sample'
contents {
from { '.' }
exclude "build"
exclude ".*"
exclude "target"

        }
    }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the Tar with:

```
mainDistTar.compression = Compression.GZIP
mainDistTar.extension = 'tar.gz'
```

OR

```
// Common distribution plugin settings for sub-modules
plugins.withType(DistributionPlugin) {
    distTar {
        compression = Compression.GZIP
        extension = 'tar.gz'
    }
}
```